# Find the row(s) with maximum number of 0s in a 2-d matrix

Tags: c++, c, algorithm, matrix

#### Problem

> Given a 2D 0/1 Matrix, Find the row(s) with maximum number of `0`s.

#### Example

> 11111000
>   11111110
>   11100000
>   11000000
>   11110000

#### Output

> 11000000

---

#### My idea

If each `0`s row is continuous, we can scan from two ends for each row. Common sense says to scan with `O(n^2)`.

Are there any `O(n)` solutions?

Comment: C or C++? **Hint:** Pick C++!

Comment: Just call it an mxm matrix and let n = m^2 then it's O(n)

Comment: There are no `O(n)` solutions. There is a little way you can 'optimize' it, but the 'optimizations' will only help in specific scenarios, and actually make it worse in others.

Comment: @muntoo be Language agnostic!

Comment: In your example all rows begin with 1 and end with 0 and a 0 is never followed by a 1. Is this a property of the 2-D matrix?

Comment: scanning a matrix is considered `O(n)`. The standard big O notation stands for relationship between run time and the input size. Since your input is of size `#rows*#cols`, you should regard this number as `n`, and not to #rows.

Comment: Traversing only requires O(n2) complexity and someone who's good at Adversary Arguments can prove that for this problem you need to go through all the nodes, giving you the complexity O(n2).

Answer (score 1):

As @amit says:

> scanning a matrix is considered O(n). The standard big O notation stands for relationship between run time and the input size. Since your input is of size #rows*#cols, you should regard this number as n, and not to #rows.

Therefore, this is as `O(n)` as you can get. :)

```
std::vector<std::string> matrix;
std::vector<std::string>::iterator max = matrix.begin();

for(std::vector<std::string>::iterator i = matrix.begin(); i != matrix.end(); ++i)
{
    if(count_zeros(*i) > count_zeros(*max))
        max = i;
}
```

`count_zeros()` should look something like this:

```
size_t count_zeros(std::string s)
{
    size_t count = 0;

    for(std::string::iterator i = s.begin(); i != s.end(); ++i)
        if(*i == '0')
            ++count;

    return i;
}
```

---

If *all* the `0`s in each row are guaranteed to be at the rightmost, you can do it in `O(sqrt(n))`.

1. Put cursor on `(len, 0)`
2. If the value to the left of the cursor is `0`, move the cursor left. Else, move it down.
3. If bottom row is reached, terminate. Else, go to step 2.

```
std::vector<std::string> matrix;
std::vector<std::string>::iterator y = matrix.begin();

for(std::string::reverse_iterator x = (*y).rbegin(); x < matrix.rend(); )
{
    if(*x != '0')
    {
        x -= (*y).rbegin();
        ++(*y);
        x += (*y).rbegin();
        continue;
    }

    ++x;
}
```

Comment: @Curi0us7 Yup; I didn't even realize it until I read amit's comment, though.

Answer (score 1):

if every row is like 1....10...0, you could binary search first zero in each row.

That would be O(n*lg(n))

for an arbitrary matrix, you must check every cell, so it must be O(n^2).

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in `O(N)` as follows:

Start at `A[i][j]` with `i=0 and j=No_of_columns-1`.

```
           0, keep moving to the left by doing j--
A[i][j] = 
           1, move down to the next row by doing i++
```

When you reach the last row or the last column, the value of j will be the answer.

Pseudo code:

```
Let R be number of rows
Let C be number of columns

Let i = 0
Let j = C-1   
Let max1Row = 0

while ( i<R && j>=0 )
   if ( matrix[i][j] == 0 )
      j--
      max1Row = i
   else
      i++
end-while


print "Max 0's = j"
print "Row number with max 0's = max1Row"
```

Comment: +1, But, as I commented above, this is `O(sqrt(n))`. When dealing with matrices, usually `#rows*#cols == n` for big O notations [because the size of input is `#rows*#cols`, and the `n` stands for the input's size].

Answer (score 0):

With the give sample set (were all starts with 111 and ends in 000 with no mix of 1 and 0) the set can simply be searched in a single pass with a test of A&(A xor B) for testing if there are more or less zero than the previous row -- that is a loop of O(n)....

Answer (score 0):

Here a quick solution with just one if or each row (not for each element):
As your matrix just holds zeros and ones, add up the elements of each row and then return the index/indices of the minimum/minimae.

P.S.: adding ones is really fast when using assmbly inc or ++Variable in C++

Edit: Here another idea. If you really just need 0/1 matrices that do not excedd say 64 columns, you could implement them as bit matrices using ordinary unsigned 64 integers. By setting and deleting the respective bit you can define the entry (0 or 1). The effect: an o(n) check (let me know if I am wrong) as followsm, where intXX is rowXX. The first idea is to extract different bits via XOR

```
SET tmpA to int01
FOR I = 1 to n-1
  XOR intI with intI+1, store result in tmpX
  AND tmpX with intI, store result in tmpM
  AND tmpX with intI+1, store result in tmpN
  if (tmpN < tmpM)
    SET tmpA to intI+1
ENDFOR
```

tmpA should now hold the (last) row with fewest zeros.

Cheers,
G.